# How to shoot an email using triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm able to send email using the following code

```
begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''127.0.0.1'''; 
          UTL_MAIL.send(
          sender => 'dssds@fhdf.com', 
                 recipients => 'kapil.agarwal@homecredit.co.in', 
                        subject => 'Deletion of an employee', 
                        message => 'An emp'     
             mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii'
           ); 
end;
```

But when I am trying to create a trigger using the run the same code as above, I'm getting an error.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TRG_emp 
AFTER DELETE ON test_kapil FOR EACH ROW 
begin
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''127.0.0.1'''; 
          UTL_MAIL.send(
          sender => 'dssds@fhdf.com', 
                 recipients => 'kapil.agarwal@homecredit.co.in', 
                        subject => 'Deletion of an employee', 
                        message => 'An emp'     
             mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii'
           ); 
end;
```

I'm not able to identify the error and resolve it. The trigger gets compiled with a warning. but the trigger does not work.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the error?

Comment: The thing is ,m not getting any error messages, as the trigger gets compiled with a warning.
Had there been  any error messages, i would've posted it here.

It's just showing a small red cross on the name of the trigger.

Comment: Can you share the trigger's compilation warning please?

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus, type `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER TRG_emp`.  If you are using some other GUI tool (e.g. SQL Developer, Toad, or PL/SQL Developer), please let us know what that is.